# FQL: Get number of likes on Fan Page post or photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to develop an iOS app for a Facebook fan page. I am trying to display all the images uploaded on the page with the number of likes. I have admin access to the page but still the query

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

returns only

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in the `post_id`. The `"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX"` in `post_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX"` stands for `page_id<underscore>post_id`. I was using only the `post_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided, your query should work perfectly if you are using a valid Access Token. The only reason why it's returning an empty list is either your post doesn't have any likes OR your Post Id is invalid. Please verify the Post Id because this query is working fine for any valid Post Id.